# Div acquiring unknown and unwanted height due to a previous floated div

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

Let's say I have a blog, and I want the sidebar floating to the right (fixed width), a slider + the content to the left not floating (fluid) and a little gap between the sidebar and the slider + content.

So to achieve that, I did what you'll find ahead.

The problem is, I have a floated `a` tag inside the content, so I used a `clearfix` on its container (the `article` tag).

But suddenly, the `article` becomes huge, and it will keep getting bigger as I add something (more `.widgets` for example) to the `.sidebar`.

What's going on? How can I prevent that? If I can't prevent tha behaviour, how can I achieve the same fluid + fixed layout?

http://jsfiddle.net/wjVDX/

```
THE HTML
------------
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="slider">
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="widget"></div>
        <div class="widget"></div>
        <div class="widget"></div>
        <div class="widget"></div>
        <div class="widget"></div>
        <div class="widget"></div>
        <div class="widget"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <article class="clearfix">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="" /></a>
            <p>This is NOT what I want</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>

THE CSS
------------
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}

.slider {
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    margin-right: 70px; /* 60px from the .sidebar + 10px margin */
}

.sidebar {
    width: 60px;
    background: blue;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px; /* Height of .slider */
    margin-bottom: -50px; /* To compensate for the position: relative; */
}

.widget {
    background: yellow;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content {
    background: green;
    margin-right: 70px; /* 60px from the .sidebar + 10px margin */
}

.content article {
    background: pink;
}

.content article a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.content article p {
    line-height: 20px;
    background: brown;
}
```

Comment: maybe overflow: hidden somewhere you could put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjVDX/3/) , adding

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to the .content should do what you asked for.

EDIT: lawnlanders had it.

Comment: You suggested adding to .container when it should have been .content. I've updated it for you..